# PHP problems getting data from table in mysql... only showing column names as data

Tags: php, mysql

I tried this but didn't work for me...I mean I am getting my table and the row count is Correct. But when I use $row['ColumnName']... I keep getting the ACTUAL name of the column and not the data itself.
If I add more rows of data to the table, I get the row count up but the data is still the same. Only Column names.

Anyone has had this issue? and how to solve it? 
php version: 5.3  and mysql version: 5.5

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('employeedb');

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee"
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['age'] . "</td></tr>";          
//$row['index']     the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
```

Comment: use `mysql_fetch_assoc` function as it will give you an associative array, also look into using the mysqli functions as the mysql api is depreciated. They are nearly the same in name and use so switching over is not that tedious

Comment: @PatrickEvans I agree with the `mysqli` statement entirely; however, [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) will also return associative values (by default; second argument specifies return type).

Comment: Consider using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Also: `mysql_` is deprecated, consider mysqli or PDO. You're also missing a `;` in your query line.

Comment: I did change my code to PDO since many said its better but still same issue, I tried with MySqli also having same issue... do not know what is wrong, if the code is standard.

Comment: Consider using `htmlspecialchars()` around arbitrary strings used in the context of HTML.  This will ensure valid HTML, and may even prevent XSS attacks in certain circumstances.

Comment: I figured it out... I am SUCH an idiot... I have the correct answer all along...

The SQL Statement was the problem... since i was used to SQL and was writing MYSql code I got confused with the Select Statement for the query... I Suppose this is why its best to use SP's... however I fixed it... thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_` is deprecated, here is some code in PDO.

```
//Open PDO connection
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname={'employeedb'}; host={'localhost'}", 'root', '');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $Exception) {
    echo "There was an error.";
}
//Query prep
$query = $db->prepare("
    SELECT *
        FROM employee
");
//Query execution; try to use prepared statements always
$query->execute();    
//create string $output
$output = "<table>";
//for rows of indeterminable quantity, use foreach()
foreach($query as $table) {
    //append to $output
    $output .= "<tr><td>";
    $output .= htmlspecialchars($table["name"]);
    $output .= "</td><td>";
    $output .= htmlspecialchars($table["age"]);
    $output .= "</td></tr>";          
}    
$output .= "</table>";
//print $output
echo $output;
//close PDO connection
$db = null;
```

As an aside, make sure to escape all output by using `htmlspecialchars()`. I would also consider having some kind of `try/catch` complex to ensure error handling is done correctly and pertinent info isn't revealed to the user.

Oh, looks like you solved it. If you're working within an undefined amount of rows, instead of using a `while()` loop, consider a `foreach()` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

can u try using numeric indexes than coloumn name. like shown below

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  

echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td><td>" . $row[1] . "</td></tr>";          

  }
```

Comment: Thanks but that was not exactly the problem :P someone downvoted you... but I gave an update to get you back to 0. 

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$db = new PDO ('localhost', 'root');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee"
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
echo '<table>';
    foreach($statement as $row){
        echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>', $row['name'],'</td>';
          echo '<td>',$row['age'],'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```